# angularjs: how to store the function returning value in one variable . based on ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, return-value, angularjs-ng-repeat

hi i am getting the intrestedid from ng-repeat , i want to call another service and store that data in one variable dynamically , because need send seperate api for getting images.

my html is look like this

```
<div class="" ng-repeat="item in items" >
  <div ng-init="MyPic = getMyprofile(item.interestedTo)">
   <img src="{{MyPic}}">
  </div>
</div>
```

My controller is look like this.

```
    $scope.getMyprofile = function(IntrstdId){
    appServices.profile( IntrstdId,  function(response){
        $scope.meDetails = response.data;
    })
    return $scope.meDetails;

   }
```

My services is look like this.

```
service.profile= function(userId, callback) {
   path = serviceUrl + '/profile/'+ userId;
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: path
        }).then(function(data) {
        callback(data)
    }, function(data) {});
}
```

but its getting undefined , any issues in this code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to resolve this by creating some abstract stub, that may be helpful to you. Please review and let me know if issue still arise

> HTML

```
<div ng-repeat ="data_ in parentData track by $index">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="result in data_.data track by $index" ng-init="counter=increaseCounter();">
         <div ng-model="counter"></div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

> Controller

```
// It simply store variable value in scope.counter
$scope.counter = 0;
$scope.increaseCounter = function () {
    var cnt = $scope.counter++;
    return cnt;
};

//Another way is to call service while update variable vaule 
$scope.counter = 0;
$scope.increaseCounter = function () {
    var cnt = $scope.counter++;
    AppService.updateValue(cnt);
    return cnt;
};
```

Comment: actually i want to pass some id and store the response...

counter=increaseCounter(result.id);

Comment: Yes you may pass it in service whatever you want

Comment: Still let me know where do you find an issue

Comment: My issue is i want to send id store that response in variable. appServices.profile( IntrstdId,  function(response){}
, "IntrstdId" is id getting from ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.getMyprofile = function(IntrstdId){
   appServices.profile( IntrstdId,  function(response){
      $scope.meDetails = response.data;
  })
return $scope.meDetails;
```

}

I think issue is this function. appService.profile is asyncronize method and before complete it function return `$scope.meDetails;`

my suggestion is to hardcore some value like in below and see the result. if it is working then you have to change the function accordingly.

```
$scope.meDetails ='some value';
return $scope.meDetails;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several best practice issue along with the async problem.

1.Avoid using `ng-init` unless you want to re-run the function when you reconstruct the element, for instance `ng-if`. It is more so when you use `ng-repeat` without `track by`, any changes in the data source would re-trigger all `ng-init` in the children.

Solution: Run them when you init the controller, or as soon as `$scope.items` is filled.

```
angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item) {
  appServices.profile(item).then(function(data){
    item.myPic = data;
  });
});

<div class="" ng-repeat="item in items" >
  <img src="{{item.myPic}}">
</div>
```

2.The correct way to wrap a function that returns promise (which `$http` is) is to return the function itself. You can research more on how to pass the resolved/rejected result around.

```
// not needed anymore, just to showcase
$scope.getMyprofile = function(IntrstdId){
  return appServices.profile( IntrstdId );
}

// same goes with the service function
service.profile= function(userId) {
  path = serviceUrl + '/profile/'+ userId;
  return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: path
  }).then(function(response) {
    return response.data;
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi , thanks a lot ,  1.)  is work for me... 

what about 2.)
$scope.getMyprofile = function(IntrstdId){
  return appServices.profile( IntrstdId );
}
i tried this but didnt get any returned value in "$scope.getMyprofile"
always showing empty {}

Comment: You can't get immediate result with that function, you need to use it in your controller by writing `$scope.getMyprofile(id).then(function(data) { // what you want to do here })`